# Visual Studio Code does not debug

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I've been using Visual Studio Code for a while and I can't debug any of my .NET and .NET Core Apps. I've tried launching, attach to process, but it just doesn't do anything when I run the task.
One time, it did change the color of the bar from blue to orange for a second before going back to blue, so I guess it tried to do something, but there was no response even after that. My colleagues never had this problem, which means something must be wrong with my editor.
I've also tried to reinstall, remove configurations, install different versions, but the same thing always happens. I'm at a loss right now, so I would be happy if anyone knows how to fix this issue.

EDIT:
I've tried reinstalling the omnisharp extension and it still doesn't work.

Here's my launch.json code:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/WebAPI/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/WebAPI.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/WebAPI",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "serverReadyAction": {
            "action": "openExternally",
            "pattern": "^\\s*Now listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
        },
        "env": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Attach",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
    }
]}
```

Comment: Try install or reinstall omnisharp extension. And share your launch config.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is to open the project I'm working on with a terminal, by navigating the directory where the `.csproj` or `.sln` is located. Then open VS Code with `code .` in the terminal.

From there, try hitting `F5` key to start the debugger, or but clicking Start Debugging through the left nav tree.

[image]

The debugger should notice you don't have any launch settings and should prompt you with what language you are trying to debug.

[image]

Then choose .NET Core if that was the case.

A `.vscode` folder should be created in your current directory with a file called `launch.json` which holds the startup settings for your project.

[image]

`launch.json` should look something like this:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/PearlMills.API/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/PearlMills.API.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/PearlMills.API",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "^\\s*Now listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then finally, hit `F5` to start the debugger and the program should start with the launch settings from `launch.json` file.

If those steps won't work, try deleting the created `.vscode` folder and/or disabling all your VS Code extensions. Then do this sequence one more time. There might a VS Code extension giving you a hard time debugging.

You can also try creating a Hello World application and try these steps again if it still wont start.

Also make sure you have the .NET SDK and runtime install on your computer.
`dotnet --info` in the terminal should display all you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following update in `launch.json` file:

```
 "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
                "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://localhost:4000"
            },
```

Added the `ASPNETCORE_URLS` for redirection.